# Read Text File From Host Server Using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, file

How i can read text file from host server using visual basic ?

Our link : yourname.com/file.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
Dim request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/readme.txt"), HttpWebRequest)
Dim response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Using sr As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine())
    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: can your give me source code ? thx

Comment: @user2007265: Yes, you can copy paste my answer if that is what you've asked. Remember to accept the answer if it works for you.